# Button (sometimes) doesn't draw StateList xml background

Tags: android, button, background

I have a wizard in my app where users can go back and forward between activities using "Back" and "Next" buttons. These buttons are the same for every activity in the wizard and are defined in their own xml layout which gets included in the the layout for each of the activities. They have a state list as their background which usually works, except once in awhile this happens:

**Expected:**

[image: Expected]

**Actual:**

[image: Actual]

**Button Definition - add_nav_buttons.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/rlAddNav"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        orientation="horizontal">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bAddBack"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:background="@drawable/b_add_nav_button"
            android:text="@string/bBack">
        </Button>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bAddNext"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:background="@drawable/b_add_nav_button"
            android:text="@string/bNext">
        </Button>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Include Example - some_activity_layout.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/rlAddMain"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <!-- OTHER STUFF -->

    <include
        android:id="@+id/NavButtons"
        layout="@layout/add_nav_buttons"
        android:layout_marginTop="-50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
    </include>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**StateList Definition - b_add_nav_button.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_enabled="false">
        <shape>
            <gradient
                android:startColor="#C7C7C7"
                android:endColor="#8B8B8B"
                android:angle="270">
            </gradient>
            <stroke
                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="#8B8B8B"> 
            </stroke>
            <padding
                android:left="10dp"
                android:right="10dp"
                android:top="10dp"
                android:bottom="10dp">
            </padding>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:state_pressed="true" >
        <shape>
            <solid
                android:color="#FFA319" />
            <padding
                android:left="10dp"
                android:right="10dp"
                android:top="10dp"
                android:bottom="10dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape>
            <gradient
                android:startColor="#4F4FB2"
                android:endColor="#24248F"
                android:angle="270">
            </gradient>
            <stroke
                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="#24248F"> 
            </stroke>
            <padding
                android:left="10dp"
                android:right="10dp"
                android:top="10dp"
                android:bottom="10dp">
            </padding>
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

I am completely baffled, any help would be much appreciated. Just to re-iterate, most of the time the expected behaviour happens, just once in awhile the background fails to draw.

I should also add that the buttons still functionally work like they're supposed to.

**Edit**

I added some debug statements and managed to reproduce. Apparently Android sometimes interprets b_add_bav_button.xml as a ColorDrawable instead of a StateListDrawable. I tried pulling the shapes out of the state list into their own xml files, no dice. I'm still equally baffled.

Comment: What happens immediately before it fails?

Comment: Nothing, there isn't a crash or any error messages or anything. Furthermore it is not reproducible in the emulator and difficult to reproduce on an actual phone (though some phones seem more prone to it than others). My thoughts are that it's some caching related issue.

Comment: Can you try putting your shape xml in a drawable and pass it with `android:drawable="@drawable/shape_xml"` in your selector?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android thought I was using a ColorDrawable instead of a StateListDrawable  which resulted in the behaviour mentioned above. I still have no idea why, but it had something to do with screen orientation (it was reproducible by starting activity, popping activity, rotating screen, and starting activity again).

My work around was to pull the <shape>'s out of the xml selector and instead build a 
StateListDrawable programmatically like so:

```
StateListDrawable d = new StateListDrawable();
d.addState(new int[]{ android.R.attr.state_pressed, android.R.attr.state_enabled }, 
           this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.b_add_nav_button_pressed));
d.addState(new int[]{ -android.R.attr.state_enabled },
           this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.b_add_nav_button_disabled));
d.addState(new int[]{ android.R.attr.state_enabled },
           this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.b_add_nav_button_normal));
bNext.setBackgroundDrawable(d);
```

There is a lot of weirdness going on, but I seem to have it working.

Answer (score 2):

Put a file "a_dummy_magic.xml" as the "topmost" drawable resource - It can be fixed in position. Only the Android SDK has such unreasonable behavior. Trust me. I experienced it and spend a whole week to find this trick.

Comment: I don't know why this worked but it did. I had a single button (out of many) showing this behavior. I expected adding a dummy file would, at best, just move the problem to another button. However, it seems to have made the problem go away. I believe my version of the failure also only occurs in the SDK.